# Why does this insert statement not match the table?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, database-project

I am using a Visual Studio 2015 Database Project to attempt to insert rows into database tables which have been created by the project.  The Insert sql works in the same table in SSMS, but not when run via the project.

I get the error:  `Column name or number of supplied values does not match the table definition.`

TSQL insert script:

```
if not exists (select top 1 1 from [dbo].[PricingGroupTypes]) begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PricingGroupTypes]
               ([Name])
         VALUES
               ('User')
               ,('Product Format')
    print 'Pricing Group Types added'
end
```

Table Definition (in DB project):

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PricingGroupTypes] (
    [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT [PK_PricingGroupTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Table Definition (via ssms):

```
USE [Toyland]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PricingGroupTypes]    Script Date: 11/14/2016 11:05:05 AM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PricingGroupTypes](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](250) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PricingGroupTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Other inserts in the same script do not seem to fail, but the overall script will roll back so the database is empty after execution.  And, like I said, the exact same script WORKS when I run it in SQL Server Management Studio.

Perhaps there's some Visual Studio setting I'm missing, but this is about the most straightforward bit of script in the entire project, so you can see why I'm perplexed.

Comment: I think it is some other Insert statement or you misplaced the brackets in your project while building the query

Comment: Does your table have a trigger?

Comment: @ChrisPratt That should give me two rows.  The ID column is generated by the database, so all I have to give is the name.

Comment: @JamesZ no triggers - the table definition is what it is.  SQL server shows a slightly different definition than what I show here.  I'll add it.

Comment: This might be a stupid question, but what version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Sounds a lot like you're either inserting into a different table you think (different schema etc) or that your statement isn't what you think. Using profiler to see what you're actually executing might help.

Comment: @MattJones  SQL Server 2012 express (11.0.2100)

Comment: I would go with @JamesZ suggestion of trying to use profiler to see what's actually going on - I can't see anything wrong with your code unfortunately.

Comment: Although your `ID` column is defined as an identity in your table schema, have you tried explicitly adding it to your insert statement, just in case the table that you're actually inserting into doesn't have it defined as an identity? I've made that mistake before. Just a thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, there was a comment here suggesting it was perhaps a problem with some other part of my overall script generated by the project.  This turned out to be the case.  I have now resolved the issue and the code in the original question is unchanged.

Unfortunately I don't know, anymore, which other part of the big script was the culprit, since I had to go through and make a few other changes to get everything running smoothly, but there did not appear to be any problems with the SQL in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

```
if not exists (select top 1 1 from [dbo].[PricingGroupTypes]) begin
    INSERT INTO [dbo].[PricingGroupTypes]
           ([Name])
         VALUES
           ('User')
           ,('Product Format')
    print 'Pricing Group Types added'
end
```

Your problem is that you're trying to insert two values into one column.  Trying to insert 'User' and 'Product Format' into [Name] will kick back an error because it needs a destination for product format.  Update your insert statement to include the second column and it should go.

Comment: I believe this is valid syntax to insert multiple rows at once. You are confusing it with `VALUES ('User', 'Product Format')`.

Comment: Although perhaps a compatibility or DB Level setting could make it interpret `VALUES ('User'),('Product Format')` as `VALUES ('User', 'Product Format')`, perhaps worth a check by the OP.

Comment: It's a SQL Server 2012 Express database.  This should be good SQL for two rows.  Also, I mentioned that this script runs successfully if I execute it within the SSMS environment, but not as part of this visual studio project.